# Entity Framework Core primary key required for CustomAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to make a project using Entity Framework, but I've run into a problem.

When the model is created (I call Database.EnsureDeleted() first) it throws:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'CustomAttributeData' requires a primary key to be defined.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNonNullPrimaryKeys(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SqliteModelValidator.Validate(IModel model)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ValidatingConvention.Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelBuilt(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_DatabaseCreator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureDeleted()
   at DAL.EF.PaperCutDbIntializer.Initialize(PaperCutDbContext ctx, Boolean recreate) in /home/jack/RiderProjects/Periode2/Papercut/DAL/EF/PaperCutDbIntializer.cs:line 13
   at DAL.EF.PaperCutDbContext..ctor() in /home/jack/RiderProjects/Periode2/Papercut/DAL/EF/PaperCutDbContext.cs:line 12
   at DAL.EF.PaperCutDbContext.Get() in /home/jack/RiderProjects/Periode2/Papercut/DAL/EF/PaperCutDbContext.cs:line 18
   at DAL.EF.TrackedItemRepository..ctor() in /home/jack/RiderProjects/Periode2/Papercut/DAL/EF/TrackedItemRepository.cs:line 10
   at BL.ItemManager..ctor() in /home/jack/RiderProjects/Periode2/Papercut/BL/ItemManager.cs:line 13
   at BL.GlobalManager..ctor() in /home/jack/RiderProjects/Periode2/Papercut/BL/GlobalManager.cs:line 17
   at CA.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/jack/RiderProjects/Periode2/Papercut/CA/Program.cs:line 16
```

Which I find rather odd because I have nothing to do with CustomAttribute.
I've tried removing all CustomAttributes from my classes as well, but that didn't make a difference. 
Maybe it's because i'm serializing an abstract class rather than an implementation?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What happens in `PaperCutDbContext`'s constructor?

Comment: Can you simplify your DbContext and entity classes enough to post a repro in your question?